# Identifying Norwegian parents of Hulda Marie Olsen who was born 1892 in North Dakota?

Tags: united-states, vital-records, 1890s, minnesota, north-dakota

I am trying to identify the parents of my paternal grandmother, Hulda Marie Olson/Olsen. From every census I have found, both parents come from Norway and I have seen her surname spelled as "Olsen" and "Olson". I know from the death certificate, Hulda was born on 13 September 1892 in Valley City, North Dakota. The first census my grandmother appears on is the 1895 Minnesota Territorial Census as "Hulda Ronne", age 2, living with "Anton Ronne". The 1900 U.S. Census has her as "Hulda Olson", the granddaughter of "Anton Rynne". I have discovered the Norwegian farm name "Rønne" has been alternately spelled as "Røyne" and "Røine", so, Anton Rynne is the same person as Anton Ronne.

If Anton Ronne/Rynne is Hulda Marie Olson's grandfather, it seems to me one of Anton Ronne.Rynne's daughters must be the mother of Hulda Marie Olson/Olsen. I have identified four daughters: Anna Ludvika, Johanna Elisabeth, Sofie Amalie and Kaia Marie. Due to the Norwegian patronymic naming conventions, I have seen various surnames for the four daughters. However, I have also discovered Anton Rønne, Johanna Rønne, Sofie Rønne and Kaia Rønne emigrated April, 1887 with the destination of Emerson, Manitoba. The only one of the daughters I have been able to find after 1887 is Kaia Ronne who appears in the same household as Anton Ronne and Hulda Ronne on the 1895 Minnesota Territorial Census.

The 1900 U.S. Census indicates there were nine total Ronne children with only three currently living. I believe the three siblings to be Martin Ronne, Henry Ronne and Kaia Ronne. At first I thought Kaia Ronne was the mother of my grandmother, however, Kaia married Hans Lee in 1898 and appears is a separate household from her father, Anton Ronne on the 1900 U.S. Census from June of that year. Also, Kaia Lee passes away in October of 1900. So, my educated guess is either Johanna Ronne or Sofie Ronne would be the mother of my grandmother, Hulda Marie Olson/Olsen but I cannot find either on any census. Nothing is known about the father, "Olson/Olsen".

Comment: I don't see how Kaia is ruled out as the mother?

Comment: If your grandmother's parents were both from Norway, the OLSEN spelling is more likely. OLSON is generally Swedish.

Comment: Olsen and Olson are interchangeable at that point in history. Census takers wrote down names phonetically, sometimes with very little knowledge of how, "ethnic" non-anglo names were spelled.